# Exit when Python gui button is clicked

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to show the results by clicking on the button, but if I press this code, the program will end in two seconds.
And 'pursent.ui' is just a widget that hasn't been set up.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic


form_class = uic.loadUiType("pursent.ui")[0]

class MyWindow(QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btneve)
    def btneve(self):
        self.statusbar.showMessage((int(self.lineEdit_2.text())-int(self.lineEdit.text()))/int(self.lineEdit.text())*100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = MyWindow()
    myWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: did you run in console/termina/cmd.exe to see if you don't get error message ? Maybe you try to convert to `int()` chars instead of digits or you divide by zero. you could also use `print()` to see what you have in `self.lineEdit_2.text()` and `self.lineEdit.text()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> void QStatusBar::showMessage(const **QString** &message, int timeout = 0)
>
> Hides the normal status indications and displays the given message for the specified number of milli-seconds (timeout).

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
#from PyQt5 import uic


#form_class = uic.loadUiType("pursent.ui")[0]

class MyWindow(QMainWindow): #, form_class):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
#        self.setupUi(self)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)  
        
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_2 = QLineEdit()

        self.pushButton = QPushButton('Button')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btneve)
        
        self.statusbar = self.statusBar() # = StatusBar(self)
        
        grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        grid.addWidget(self.lineEdit)  
        grid.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        grid.addWidget(self.pushButton)        
        
        
    def btneve(self):
        self.statusbar.showMessage(str(                          # + str
            (int(self.lineEdit_2.text())-int(self.lineEdit.text()))/int(self.lineEdit.text())*100)
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = MyWindow()
    myWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]